# Why is XmlNodeList disposable?

Tags: .net, xml, idisposable

I could not find an answer to this question.

Just out of curiosity, why does the [XmlNodeList class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implement IDisposable in .NET 4.5 when it didn't in the previous versions?

Comment: Looking at decompiled code, it seems to have something to do with unregistering from events that fire when the parent document changes. But I couldn't understand what exactly does the event handler do or why (the called method is called `ConcurrencyCheck()`).

Comment: This turned out to be a major performance issue for my legacy product which was compiled under 4.0, but was running against 4.5. Uncollected XmlNodeLists ended up in a finalizer queue. Soft cast to IDisposable seems to be the only reasonable fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely for the same reason that `IEnumerator<T>` implements `IDisposable` but `IEnumerator` does not--the earlier version was written before the authors thought of circumstances where one an a implementation might need cleanup, but a factory returning such an implementation might not know about such need.  For example, a class might accept a file name and offer up a "live" `XmlNodeList` from that file; the `IDisposable.Dispose` method of the `XmlList` would close the underlying file.  If any significant fraction of users of an interface or abstract class would have to use code like:

```
IDisposable asDispos = thing as IDisposable;
if (asDispos != null)
  asDispos.Dispose();
```

and if many of those that don't, should, then the thing should probably implement `IDisposable` itself, since it's faster to unconditionally call `IDisposable.Dispose` on a class which is known to implement `IDisposable`, than it is to try casting a class that may or may not implement `IDisposable.Dispose`.