# Should I dispose XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, .net

In the following code I get an `XmlNodeList` as return value from `XmlDocument.SelectNodes()`

```
foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes(xPath))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

As it turns out, `XmlNodeList` implements `IDisposable`. Does that mean that each time I want to iterate the return value of `XmlDocument.SelectNodes()` I should put that in a local variable and make sure it gets disposed (i.e. put it in a `using` block)?

Like this:

```
using(XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes(xPath))
{ 
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
    {
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14398798/why-is-xmlnodelist-disposable

Comment: @Chris: I saw that. It does not make it clear to me though whether I should call Dispose() or not in general as @AgentFire points out, I obviously should. It does make `SelectNodes()` less appealing though.

Comment: I agree - having to dispose it is no fun. Personally I think I'm going to forget I ever read this and keep on as before without disposing...

Comment: Why dont you guys just use XDocument instead??

Comment: @AgentFire: Because that would mean rewriting code that has been in production for years. Given a good reason, I would certainly do that. But lacking that I would rather spend my time doing something else.

Comment: @PetervanderHeijden hehe, well, in that case you are stuck in the ancient techlonogies.

Comment: See the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228593.aspx), section 8.8.4 to learn about `foreach` and `IDisposable`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: `foreach` (creates and) disposes an `IEnumerator`, not the `IEnumerable`, see here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The System.Xml namespace is, erm, wonky.  Nicest way I could possibly put it.  XmlNodeList is an abstract class, it inherits IDisposable and implements the disposable pattern but otherwise doesn't do anything itself.

There are three internal classes that derive from XmlNodeList.  One of them actually overrides the Dispose(bool) method, XmlElementList.  That class has a private field of type XmlElementListener.  Yet another internal class, not that obvious what it does but it appears to "listen" to list changes.  The Dispose method (wait for it) unsubscribes two event handlers.

This breaks every rule in the book, it is *never* correct to abuse IDisposable for that.  Unfortunately you'll have to walk the walk, it is next to impossible to unravel this to see whether that listener ever gets instantiated and whether those event handlers will cause a long lasting leak in your program if you don't call Dispose().  You'd better call it.

Lots of awesome code in the .NET Framework.  Good code always needs bad code to make it obvious how good the good code is.  That's System.Xml's job.

Comment: Which part "breaks every rule in the book"? Or is it all of it?

Comment: `IDisposable` is intended for any deterministic general-purpose clean-up, not just for handling unmanaged resources. Microsoft changed their tune on this some time ago. See the observer pattern for exactly the same usage pattern. This is not breaking any rules.

Comment: I'd better invoke the native English speakers for that: https://www.google.com/#q=eric+lippert+idisposable+abuse

Comment: Respect to Eric, he is a good dev but he does not make the rules. He does make some good points, and I do think it's a very fine line. I consider Microsoft's use of `IDisposable` here to be on the good side of that line.

Comment: Also, your English is exceptional :). I would not have known.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer and your consoling words about the merits of bad code. I guess I will walk the walk as you suggest, or use another API after all.